# Inputting ID variable into GraphQL query not returning data

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm setting up a GraphQL API at the moment, and the resolver for one of my queries isn't functioning as expected when I pass in a variable.

I've set up some mock-data, which is imported in to my resolver file:

```
export const research = [
    {
        id: "1",
        team_id: "123",
        title: "Example research with ID 1",
        description: "A description, wow!",
    }
]
```

I then have a type of Research defined in my typeDefs, like so:

```
type Research {
    id: ID!
    team_id: ID!
    title: String! 
    description: String 
  }
```

In my Query type, I define fetching a single Research type from my array like so:

```
type Query {
    single_research(id: ID!): Research!
  }
```

Finally, I have my resolvers object, which looks like this:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      single_research: (id) => {
        return research.filter(item => item.id === id) 
      }
    },
  };
```

Basically, I pass in the research_id, as defined in the schema, which is of type 'ID'. I then filter the mock data to just return the research item which matches the particular item 'ID' with the passed in research_id.

However, every time I run it, it returns this error:

```
"data": {},
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Research.title.",
    }
  ]
```

I know I'm missing something really obvious here, but it doesn't make sense why it's not working. If anybody has any pointers, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

`research.filter()` is returning an array when what you want is a single object. Use `research.find()` instead.

Comment: That's not it unfortunately - I'll update my original question with example containing title.

Comment: For the record - the fetch works fine if I omit the variable, so it's something related to that.